# How can i convert a equation into a working circuit

Tags: conversion, circuit-design, formula-derivation

How can i convert a Equation into working circuit 
For Ex : Eb (Back EMF) = V - IR (Copper losses) of a motor.
How can i convert the above equation into a working circuit having variable & as well as non variable constants ??

Comment: This smells like you are asking about a supposed solution instead of the root problem itself.  If your purpose is to measure the back EMF of a motor, this isn't how to go about it.  But since that's now what you asked about, there is no point going into details about this misconception.  Pop up two levels and tell us what the real problem is.

Comment: Are you after hardware in the loop modeling?

Comment: An electric motor is a working implementation of that equation. So what exactly is it you want?

Comment: @OlinLathrop its not about measuring Back EMF but instead i want a method to make a circuitry Controlling the Back EMF of a DC motor, by using the back EMF equation & taking its speed, current, Voltage parameters & using them as it's feedback...

Comment: You don't (directly) control the back-EMF of a motor. The properties of the motor determine what its back-EMF will be, depending on external factors like the power supplied to the motor and the load placed on it.

Comment: @brhans the motor used here in this case is in steel mill Rolls

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your equation "Eb (Back EMF) = V - IR (Copper losses)". The back EMF is determined by the number of coils and the geometry of the magnetic fields. Copper loss is determined by the length and diameter of the copper wires. Can you easily change either of these things? Not without taking the motor apart and rebuilding it.

So the answer is, basically, that for a given motor these numbers are indeed constants. And the nature of constants is that you cannot change them. If you could change them they would be variables, but they are not.

Comment: Fyi... Ke,kt are variable

Comment: @JonRB - in real time? Without changing motor geometry/construction/materials?

Comment: Well my point was ke,kt have alot of variability with then (temp, saturation...) But yes, kt can be influenced by the user (the apparent kt) via phase advance or field weakening